# How do I keep a line number count when using reader.eachLine to read a BufferedInputStream?

Tags: groovy

How can I keep track of the line number I'm on when using eachLine to read a BufferedInputStream?

```
def input = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f))
def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))
reader.eachLine {
    line ->if(line.contains(searchString)){
        println "${f} - ${line}"
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean besides tracking it yourself?

Comment: I guess I'm asking if there's a built-in way to do it or if I should just declare a variable and increment it from within the closure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closure you pass to eachLine can also take 2 parameters.  First being the line of data and the second being the line number.

```
....
....
reader.eachLine { line, lineNumber ->
    if(line.contains(searchString)) {
        println "${lineNumber} - ${line}"
    }
}
```

See [GDK Doc for InputStream eachLine method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html#eachLine(groovy.lang.Closure)).

Comment: Note that despite what the documentation says, the line number seems to start at 0, not 1.

Comment: By default it starts at 1, but you can pass an argument to set the starting line count, reader.eachLine(0) { ... }.  Just tried and by default line number starts with 1 as documented.